# Custom Layout in QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview

I'm looking for a way to create a custom layout in the QListView.

The problem is the following: I have a number of images, with different widths (height is the same). In code, these images are stored in QAbstractItemModel. I want to lay them out similar to "justified" layout in text editors, i.e. in each row there's an image in the start and in the end of the row, images in between are placed uniformly. Spaces between images on the same row should be equal.

I didn't find this customization functionality in Qt docs nor in google.
How can I achieve custom layout like this using Qt?

Here's the image, showing an example of the layout I need:

[image]

Comment: If you sub-class `QAbstractItemModel`, you might handle `Qt::SizeHintRole` data in the model's `data()` function to provide size of your items (images in your case).

Comment: The view knows sizes, it just layouts items not the way I need. Following the analogy with text editors, the layout QListView gives me is "align left", while I need "justify".

Comment: @mbabenko You must create your own view, for that you should inherit from QAbstractItemView.

Comment: How are they stored in the item model? How are the rows organized in the model? What is this widget intended for? Is selection functionality intended, and on what granularity? Many questions.. You could make use of `QListView`, I think, and install a custom delegate. Each row in your drawing would be a row in the list view. If it doesn't need to be dynamic, just populating a `QTextEdit` with a HTML table that contains these images would seem to be the easiest and quickest solution.

Comment: @litb. The items in the model are stored as a list of QPixmaps. You can think of it as having std::vector<QPixmap> in the model, and data() function just returns one element of that vector. The widget is intended just to show images, no selection, drag&drop and other stuff. Custom delegate would allow me to draw single item customly, but not the whole row. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do that a while back, the result is this library: [longscroll-qt](https://github.com/TripleWhy/longscroll-qt). It does not use `QAbstractItemModel` however, since its structure does not fit the problem.

It solves all the nasty stuff, like what to do when there image sizes + spacings do not add up. And it supports real custom widgets to display items, that you can interact with (like pressing a button), which is not really possible in `QAbstractItemViews`.